# O que usar no lugar de "--use-mirrors" no PIP?

Tags: python, pip

Ao rodar o seguinte comando eu obtenho a seguinte resposta:

```
sudo pip install --use-mirrors -r test-infra/requirements.txt

Usage:   
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --use-mirrors
```

Lendo em https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/ descobri que os seguintes comandos foram removidos na versão 7.0.0:

> BACKWARD INCOMPATIBLE Removed the deprecated `--mirror`, `--use-mirrors`, and `-M` options.

O que usar no lugar de `--use-mirrors`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nada. Simplesmente não ponha a opção - deixe `pip install  -r test-infra/requirements.txt`

Hoje não há mirrors da Loja PyPi original - suponho que a melhoria em escalabilidade de sistemas em rede tenha eliminado isso ao longo dos últimos anos.

É possível sim configurar o PIP para buscar pacotes em outros sistemas compatíveis com o pipy  - e muitas organizações/empresas estabelecem seus repositórios privados. Mas os parâmetros para isso são outros, e a finalidade é diferente do que teria sido o "user mirrors" no passado.

Agora um aspecto relacionado, mas que não é o que você perguntou: você não deveria usar PIP em conjunto com  `sudo` em nenhuma distribuição Linux. Acontece que a forma que o PIP não rgistra os arquivos que instala e baixa junto ao gerenciador de arquivos do seu Linux (seja o apt-get nos derivdos do debian, ou dnf no fedora e RedHat, ou qualquer outro): então quando você for atualizar pacotes de Python pelo gerenciador do Linux - e isso acontece naturalmente na manutenção do seu sistema, vai haver conflito desses arquivos.

Em suma - o hábito de usar `sudo pip install ...`  potencialmente, emuito provavelmente, vai estragar seu Linux!

O PIP deve ser usado em ambientes locais de projetos de Python, criados com o comando virtualenv - veja aqui em português: http://www.devfuria.com.br/python/virtualenv/   (mas claro, ao contrário do que ensinam nessa página, instale o SEU virtualenv no Linux com `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv` ou o comando equivalente do Linux - não com pip)

Comment: Foi exatamente o que pensei, só não tinha certeza, vou fazer mais uns testes e no fim de semana talvez eu marque a resposta :) +1

Comment: Após um teste, entendi o porque estava usando `sudo` no repositório que estou tentando trabalhar, é por causa de um "pacote" que faz o teste na infraestrutura, de qualquer maneira a duvida foi resolvida, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar [--index-url](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#index-url) ou [--extra-index-url](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#cmdoption--extra-index-url) para determinar manualmente os mirrors do pacote, veja o changelog:

> BACKWARD INCOMPATIBLE pip no longer supports the --use-mirrors, -M,
>   and --mirrors flags. The mirroring support has been removed. In order
>   to use a mirror specify it as the primary index with -i or
>   --index-url, or as an additional index with --extra-index-url. (PR #1098, CVE-2013-5123)

Comment: Poderia fornecer um exemplo? Não sei bem como usar